# Give idea to display the datetime in my aspx page.like digital clock

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime

Each and every second the datetime will be updated like a digital clock.

formate like:YYYY:MM::DD:HH:MM:DD:A.M

Comment: Nothing on this site annoys me more than downvoters who don't leave a comment explaining why. How are people supposed to learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to update every second you will need to use javascript to do this.

There are hundreds of examples out there, [here is one](http://www.ricocheting.com/code/javascript/html-generator/digital-clock) for you.

Comment: ya good response.. i tell my idea.if the person enter his time of birth in this formate "YYYY:MM::DD:HH:MM:SS" My application will display.
This is ur timer:"26:11:13:02:03:55":